# NFC intent on TabActivity starts a new activity instead of refreshing existing one

Tags: android, refresh, nfc, tabactivity, android-pendingintent

*After [my old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12322324/nfc-intent-on-tabactivity-starts-new-activity-instead-of-changing-content-of-exi) was closed I'm trying it now again considering the advices you gave me...*

I've got an Android-Test-App in which I want to change the text a TextView as soon as something (f.e. RFID chip) is read with NFC.

The problem is that my activity with the TextView lies in the Tab of a TabHost. When NFC is reading something the Activity is started in the foreground and the TextView is not changed.
What I want is that only the TextView changes and everything else stays as it is....

Here's my code:

**My TabActivity:**

```
public class NfcTabsActivity extends TabActivity {

    private NfcAdapter nfc;
    private PendingIntent nfcintent;
    private String[][] nfctechfilter = new String[][] { new String[] { NfcA.class.getName() } };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

        Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(this, NfcTest.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("nfctab").setIndicator("NFC").setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        nfc = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);

            // PendingIntent using the NfcTest-Activity to receive the Intent. (Am I doing this correctly??)
        nfcintent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
    }

    // Start looking for NFC when activity is started/resumed.
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        nfc.enableForegroundDispatch(this, nfcintent, null, nfctechfilter);
    }

    // Disable NFC when leaving activity
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        nfc.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
    }
}
```

and here's **my NfcTest Activity** that should receive the intent when NFC is used:

```
public class NfcTest extends Activity {

    private TextView status;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.nfctest);

        status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    }

    @Override
    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {

        status.setText("RFID detected...");

    }
}
```

Thanks **NFC guy** for the advice to put the PendingIntent in the TabActivity!
Unfortunately - as I said in the other thread - that doesn't work neither for me... :( Maybe I did something wrong in my code?

Here's the activity definition in my **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
        [...]
        <activity android:name=".NfcTest" android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true" android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"></activity>
        [...]
```

Can anyone help me with this problem?
Maybe you NFC guy? Maybe I only understand something wrong on your idea or mixed something up in my code...? :/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
        Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(this, NfcTest.class);

    TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("nfctab").setIndicator("NFC").setContent(intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
```