# Losing tabs when scanning an NFC tag -android

Tags: android, tabs, nfc

I have an app that has a tab layout. One main activity with the tabhost/tabspecs/intents etc and three others in which I want to read NFC tags using enableForegroundDispatch.

My problem is that when I read the tag from one of the three activities, the activity gets loaded up anew, replacing the tabbed layout.

I think it's to do with the activity I'm calling in my pending intent, but I can't work out, or find on the web, anything about how to keep the tabbed layout.

I'm not sure if maybe I should be switching to fragments because possibly tabs with activities can't handle this functionality?

Thanks in advance.

Russ

p.s. I can include code if it helps, but I'm hoping people have dealt with this before, though it does seem to be asked on here a few times with no answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known problem (see for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13558219/android-tabhost-missing-when-nfc-scanned) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12378857/nfc-intent-on-tabactivity-starts-a-new-activity-instead-of-refreshing-existing-o)). A solution is to do the NFC intent handling in a TabActivity with launchMode set to singleTask (not necessarily a nice solution). Better is to switch to using fragments, I would say. Then there will be only one Activity, which then can handle the NFC intents.

Comment: yeah I'd read those two links already (they were what I was referring to by not seeing any answers on SO).

It was for a small hackathon style project at work which has now finished so no need to fix it, but if I get time I may try to get fragments working to see if that solves it. Thanks for answering